# What is the fastest heat can travel? The perfect solid heat sink

Tags: thermodynamics, speed-of-light, radiation, elements

What dictates the conductivity of heat in an element or medium? Consider the shape, volume, area, and distance heat travels from vibrating atom to atom, not through the excitement of the an atom through transference of energy e.i.e. light radiation or the compressing of air. How heat travel along a wire, is not the same as electricity does. So, what is the scale, a particular configuration, if built, can a non-moving object move heat from a to b best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest heat can move is the speed of sound. Normally phonons, excitations in the crystal lattice of a solid, will move until they scatter off some inhomogeneity such as a dislocation, foreign element or other imperfection. This means that after some distance (the mean free path) the phonon bounces in random direction, making it diffuse like normal (the distance travelled is proportional to the square root of time). But in very perfect crystals (usually 1D structures like [nanowires](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep41794)) the transport becomes [ballistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction): phonons start moving freely, with $d\propto t$ instead of $d\propto \sqrt{t}$.

So clearly perfect, low-dimensional crystals work great. Is there a theoretical way of analysing this? Yes, this is [transport theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transport_theory) in statistical mechanics (which also deals with electrical conduction: they are not that different). In particular, the [transport coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_coefficient) (in this case heat conductivity) can in principle be calculated from theory using [the Green-Kubo formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Kubo_relations) and its [quantum versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula).

Comment: I think your answer is perfectly valid for phonon mediated heat transport. And indeed the question seems to be focussed on that. However, I think that for materials with strong electron phonon coupling, heat will also be transferred by electrons. I guess then the speed is no longer limited by the sound velocity.